# Run drush cc from host using bind mounts

Tags: docker, drupal, drush

I managed to have some containers with this config in order to run a Drupal app:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  drupal:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./workspace
        target: /opt/workspace
    networks:
      - beayoga
    restart: always


  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.2
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - beayoga
    restart: always

  pgadmin:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=foo@bar.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=foobar
    networks:
      - beayoga

volumes:
  pg_data:

networks:
  beayoga:
```

It is working well, when changing a file from my host I can see the changes in my container (using the interactive terminal) and when changing a file from the my container I can see the changes in my host.

When I want to see the changes, I have to run this command:

`./vendor/bin/drush cc`

When I run it from my container, I get this:

```sh
www-data@5c6c061c1519:/opt/workspace$ ./vendor/bin/drush cc       
 Choose a cache to clear [all]:
  [0] Cancel
  [1] drush
  [2] theme-registry
  [3] router
  [4] css-js
  [5] render
  [6] plugin
  [7] bin
  [8] views
```

Then I can choose `[5]` to see the changes in my webpage.

I want to run this same command from my host, so that in the future, I won't need to connect to the container with the interactive terminal.

When I run the exact same command, from my host, I get this:

```sh
➜  workspace git:(dev) ✗ ./vendor/bin/drush cc
 Choose a cache to clear [all]:
  [0] Cancel
  [1] drush
```

I only have those two options that are displayed, and I cannot choose `[5] render`

**Does somebody know what is happening and how can I get the whole list of choices ?**

### What I've tried so far:

I see some answers on google suggesting that it could be something related to the database. So I installed **psql** in my host and added the name of the **postgres** container in my `/etc/hosts` file (using the ip given when running `docker inspect`), but I still had the same 2 items showing in the list with no more...

## Edit

*To answer @Patrick W comment:*

**Render and status on remote (container)**

```sh
www-data@5c6c061c1519:/opt/workspace$ ./vendor/bin/drush cc render
 [success] 'render' cache was cleared.
www-data@5c6c061c1519:/opt/workspace$ ./vendor/bin/drush status   
 Drupal version   : 9.1.4                                       
 Site URI         : http://default                              
 DB driver        : pgsql                                       
 DB hostname      : postgres                                    
 DB port          : 5432                                        
 DB username      : postgres                                    
 DB name          : postgres_development                        
 Database         : Connected                                   
 Drupal bootstrap : Successful                                  
 Default theme    : my_custom_theme                             
 Admin theme      : seven                                       
 PHP binary       : /usr/local/bin/php                          
 PHP config       :                                             
 PHP OS           : Linux                                       
 Drush script     : /opt/workspace/vendor/drush/drush/drush     
 Drush version    : 10.4.0                                      
 Drush temp       : /tmp                                        
 Drush configs    : /opt/workspace/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml 
 Install profile  : standard                                    
 Drupal root      : /opt/workspace/web                          
 Site path        : sites/default                               
 Files, Public    : sites/default/files                         
 Files, Temp      : /tmp
```

**Render and status on host**

```sh
➜  workspace git:(dev) ✗ ./vendor/bin/drush cc render 

In CacheCommands.php line 261:
                                                                                                                                                                                
  'render' cache requires a working Drupal site to operate on. Use the --root and --uri options, or a site @alias, or cd to a directory containing a Drupal settings.php file.  
                                                                                                                                                                                

➜  workspace git:(dev) ✗ ./vendor/bin/drush status   
 Drupal version : 9.1.4                                                              
 Site URI       : http://default                                                     
 DB driver      : pgsql                                                              
 DB hostname    : postgres                                                           
 DB port        : 5432                                                               
 DB username    : postgres                                                           
 DB name        : postgres_development                                               
 PHP binary     : /usr/bin/php                                                       
 PHP config     : /etc/php.ini                                                       
 PHP OS         : Linux                                                              
 Drush script   : /home/david/Desktop/beayoga/workspace/vendor/drush/drush/drush     
 Drush version  : 10.4.0                                                             
 Drush temp     : /tmp                                                               
 Drush configs  : /home/david/Desktop/beayoga/workspace/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml 
 Drupal root    : /home/david/Desktop/beayoga/workspace/web                          
 Site path      : sites/default
```

However I'm in the exact same directory, since they are bound together...

Do you know how Drupal gets to know if it is installed ? Maybe it try to look on another folder which isn't on the host ?

Comment: What output do you get when you run `./vendor/bin/drush cc render` on the remote? When I usually get only Cancel/drush options it means my command isn't happening in the right place, what's the output of `./vendor/bin/drush status`?

Comment: @PatrickW Thanks for your reply, I edited my question with the informations

Comment: Ok, it looks like the remote drush commands aren't being run in the drupal docroot. Try running `ls` to see if you're outside the docroot. Alternatively, drush is recommending that you `Use the --root and --uri options, or a site @alias, or cd to a directory containing a Drupal settings.php file.` (i.e. https://docs.drush.org/en/9.x/usage/#using-the-uri-option-and-root-options).